# Join two arrays into a single one

Tags: php, array

I put together a function to sort out values that I am getting from a curl request for different 'devices', it works as is, I am only wondering if there is an easier way to to this.

```
function convert($deviceName, $namesArray, $devicesArray) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($devicesArray as $d) {
        $result [] = [
            'Device Type' => $deviceName,
            'Device' => $d[0],
            $namesArray[0] => $d[1],
            $namesArray[1] => $d[2],
            $namesArray[2] => $d[3],
            $namesArray[3] => $d[4],
            $namesArray[4] => $d[5],
            $namesArray[5] => $d[6],
            $namesArray[6] => $d[7],
            $namesArray[7] => $d[8],
            $namesArray[8] => $d[9],
            $namesArray[9] => $d[10]
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

it takes in the following:

```
$namesArray = [ Operating System, Physical Size, Physical Size, Width, Height, Device-width, Px Per Inch, Px Density, Aspect Ratio, Popularity];

$devicesArray = 
Array
(

    [0] => Array
            (
            [0] => iPhone 4 (4, 4S)
            [1] => iOS
            [2] => 3.5
            [3] => 8.9
            [4] => 640
            [5] => 960
            [6] => 320
            [7] => 326
            [8] => 200% XHDPI
            [9] => 2 : 3
            [10] => 8.8
            )

    [1] => Array
            (
            [0] => iPhone 5 (5c, 5s)
            [1] => iOS
            [2] => 4.0
            [3] => 10.0
            [4] => 640
            [5] => 1136
            [6] => 320
            [7] => 326
            [8] => 200% XHDPI
            [9] => 40 : 71
            [10] => 7.9
            )
)

 and $deviceName field which can be 'Phone', 'Tablet' or 'Monitor'.
```

This gives the output

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Device Type] => Phone
            [Device] => iPhone 4 (4, 4S)
            [Operating System] => iOS
            [Physical Size] => 8.9
            [Width] => 640
            [Height] => 960
            [Device-width] => 320
            [Px Per Inch] => 326
            [Px Density] => 200% XHDPI
            [Aspect Ratio] => 2 : 3
            [Popularity] => 8.8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Device Type] => Phone
            [Device] => iPhone 5 (5c, 5s)
            [Operating System] => iOS
            [Physical Size] => 10.0
            [Width] => 640
            [Height] => 1136
            [Device-width] => 320
            [Px Per Inch] => 326
            [Px Density] => 200% XHDPI
            [Aspect Ratio] => 40 : 71
            [Popularity] => 7.9
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `$devicesArray` to `$devices`.  It is obvious enough that each device would contain an array of information.
2. Change `$namesArray` to `$deviceFields` it is more meaningful.
3. Change `$deviceName` to `$deviceType`. `$deviceName` seems to be misleading.
4. Use `$device` instead of `$d` in the foreach loop, it is more meaningful.
5. `'Device'` is a field and should be the first field in `$deviceFields`. This is required for the following improvement.
6. Use array functions to combine the arrays:
   `array('Device Type' => $deviceType]) + array_combine($deviceFields, $device)`.

The function then becomes:

```
function convert($deviceType, $deviceFields, $devices) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($devices as $device) {
        $result[] =
            ['Device Type' => $deviceType] +
            array_combine($deviceFields, $device);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: tnx, but, gives error : array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements, so a minor correction to your code will be to add  ['Device' => array_shift($device)] +  before the array_combine..